# I need help understanding Session/Cookie data.

Tags: php, session-variables, session-cookies

I'm moving some features of an existing site over to a new site for a client. A couple of the things they are using in the existing site are new to me - namely session data and cookies. I think I have found all of the code that is working with these two things, but when I move the code into the new site, I get errors. This is the code:

```
//* Store Session information
function store_session_information() {
    $nameKey = 'OnTracUserInfo_Name';
    $districtNameKey = 'OnTracUserInfo_DistrictName';
    $districtCodeKey = 'OnTracUserInfo_DistrictCode';
    $schoolKey = 'OnTracUserInfo_School';
    $emailKey = 'OnTracUserInfo_Email';
    $tokenKey = 'OnTracUserInfo_Token';
    $setAtTimestampKey = 'OnTracUserInfo_setAtTimestampKey';
    $hitAtTimestampKey = 'OnTracUserInfo_hitAtTimestampKey';
    $incrementKey = 'OnTracUserInfo_incrementKey';
    $hitCountKey = 'OnTracUserInfo_hitCountKey';

if (empty($_SESSION[$hitCountKey])){
    $_SESSION[$hitCountKey] = 1;
}
else
{
    $_SESSION[$hitCountKey] = $_SESSION[$hitCountKey] + 1;
}
$_SESSION[$hitAtTimestampKey] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

if(
    $_REQUEST[$nameKey] != ""
    || $_REQUEST[$districtNameKey] != ""
    || $_REQUEST[$districtCodeKey] != ""
    || $_REQUEST[$schoolKey] != ""
    || $_REQUEST[$emailKey] != ""
    || $_REQUEST[$tokenKey] != ""
) {
    $_SESSION[$nameKey] = $_REQUEST[$nameKey];
    $_SESSION[$districtNameKey] = $_REQUEST[$districtNameKey];
    $_SESSION[$districtCodeKey] = $_REQUEST[$districtCodeKey];
    $_SESSION[$schoolKey] = $_REQUEST[$schoolKey];
    $_SESSION[$emailKey] = $_REQUEST[$emailKey];
    $_SESSION[$tokenKey] = $_REQUEST[$tokenKey];

    $_SESSION[$setAtTimestampKey] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    if (empty($_SESSION[$incrementKey])){
        $_SESSION[$incrementKey] = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION[$incrementKey] = $_SESSION[$incrementKey] + 1;
    }

}
}

//* Write session variables to JS variables
add_action( 'wp_head', 'set_js_session_variables');

function set_js_session_variables() {
    $nameKey = 'OnTracUserInfo_Name';
    $districtNameKey = 'OnTracUserInfo_DistrictName';
    $districtCodeKey = 'OnTracUserInfo_DistrictCode';
    $schoolKey = 'OnTracUserInfo_School';
    $emailKey = 'OnTracUserInfo_Email';
    $tokenKey = 'OnTracUserInfo_Token';
    $setAtTimestampKey = 'OnTracUserInfo_setAtTimestampKey';
    $hitAtTimestampKey = 'OnTracUserInfo_hitAtTimestampKey';
    $incrementKey = 'OnTracUserInfo_incrementKey';
    $hitCountKey = 'OnTracUserInfo_hitCountKey';

    store_session_information();

    echo '
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var onTracUserInfo = {};
        onTracUserInfo.name = \'' . $_SESSION[$nameKey] . '\';
        onTracUserInfo.districtname = \'' . $_SESSION[$districtNameKey] . '\';
        onTracUserInfo.districtcode = \'' . $_SESSION[$districtCodeKey] . '\';
        onTracUserInfo.school = \'' . $_SESSION[$schoolKey] . '\';
        onTracUserInfo.email = \'' . $_SESSION[$emailKey] . '\';
        onTracUserInfo.token = \'' . $_SESSION[$tokenKey] . '\';
        onTracUserInfo.setAtTimestamp = \'' . $_SESSION[$setAtTimestampKey] . '\';
        onTracUserInfo.increment = \'' . $_SESSION[$incrementKey] . '\';
        onTracUserInfo.hitAtTimestamp = \'' . $_SESSION[$hitAtTimestampKey] . '\';
        onTracUserInfo.hitCount = \'' . $_SESSION[$hitCountKey] . '\';
    </script>
    ';
}
```

The error message I receive is this: 
Undefined index: OnTracUserInfo_Name

for every one of these:

```
$nameKey = 'OnTracUserInfo_Name';
$districtNameKey = 'OnTracUserInfo_DistrictName';
$districtCodeKey = 'OnTracUserInfo_DistrictCode';
$schoolKey = 'OnTracUserInfo_School';
$emailKey = 'OnTracUserInfo_Email';
$tokenKey = 'OnTracUserInfo_Token';
$setAtTimestampKey = 'OnTracUserInfo_setAtTimestampKey';
$hitAtTimestampKey = 'OnTracUserInfo_hitAtTimestampKey';
$incrementKey = 'OnTracUserInfo_incrementKey';
$hitCountKey = 'OnTracUserInfo_hitCountKey';
```

I guess I must be missing something that is setting the items like "OnTracUserInfo_Name" to some index number. But I don't have a clue in the world where that info could or should be coming from. Am I missing an obvious piece here that someone with more experience could instantly spot?

Comment: Does the name "OnTrac" look familiar to you? Is it used elsewhere in the code? There is probably another script (library, class, etc.) that is supposed to set session parameters before this script gets called.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way for me to check to see what parameters might be set using the console? I could check the other site to see if session parameters exist.

Comment: Using the console? What kind of console? Like a terminal connected to the server?

Comment: No just the console in the browser window. Web Inspector or whatnot.

Comment: Ah. Well, you could just add `<script> var _SESSION = <?= json_encode($_SESSION) ?>;</script>` somewhere in the `<body>` of the page generated in a PHP script, and then open up the console on the web browser open to that page and inspect the _SESSION variable.

Comment: Ok thank you. I added the script to the header for the site. How do I inspect that variable?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113671/discussion-between-williamalexander-and-cyberbit).